# Why Thread.ofVirtual() and Thread.ofPlatform() named like that?

Tags: java, project-loom

Why the new methods proposed by JEP 425: Virtual Threads (Preview) are named like that?
Given that they return `OfVirtual` and `OfPlatform` builder classes, it seems inconsistent with the other usages of `of` in the standard library.
The `of` static factory method naming convention up to this point was (quote from Effective Java by Joshua Bloch):

> An aggregation method that takes multiple parameters and returns an instance of this type that incorporates them

I could not find a public discussion e.g. in the loom-dev mailing list and weary of asking there for being accused of bikeshedding. I think that naming is important and this feels like a mistake.

Comment: Perhaps this is better posted to the *Project Loom* mailing list rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: `of()` is not the same as `ofPlatform()` / `ofVirtual()`. It would be ridiculous for Effective Java to forbid any and all uses of the word `of` alone or in combination except for the meaning of aggregating multiple parameters.